# Binomial formula when the probability is 1/2

Tags: probability

P48 of *Intro to Pr*, 2nd Ed by Bertsekas and Tsitsiklis describes a simplification to the binomial formula when the probability is $\dfrac12$.  I don't understand how it is derived.

[image: http://imgur.com/LZ3T2l1]

If the probability is $p = \dfrac12$, shouldn't the formula be $$\sum_{k=0}^n {{n} \choose {k}}p^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {{n} \choose {k}}(1/2)^n $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, where $p=\frac{1}{2}$, and your sum is equal to 1. If you multiply both sides by $2^n$, you get the given formula.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I don't understand this still.  I do understand how the sum of all n choose k equals 2^n.  That just ends up being the set of all subsets which has 2^n elements.  What I don't understand is what the 1/2 probability has to do with deriving that formula.

Comment: Using your above formula $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}p^n=1$ for $p=\frac{1}{2}$, so $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n=1$, so $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}=2^n$.

Comment: ahh i see. Thanks!